# Spring 6 http interfaces with MultipartFile

Tags: spring

I have that endpoint (generated)

```
@HttpExchange(
    method = "POST",
    value = "/upload",
    accept = "application/json",
    contentType = "multipart/form-data"
)
ResponseEntity<String> upload(
     @RequestPart(value = "info", required = false) Info info,
     @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file
);
```

How can I use it for the MultiparFile ?

I my code I have

```
private byte[] content;
private Info info;

myApi.upload(info, ...???);
```

As I read somewhere I tried creating a class that implements MultipartFile with

```
@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
}
```

But it is not working.  I have an exception like

```
caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
```

Comment: It is not supported in Spring 6.0, support is coming in Spring 6.1.